# Why convert pdf to swf ?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, web-applications, web, flash

Pros and cons ?

Im a newbie developer ,  and currently working on a project. It involves viewing of files. Most of which are originally pdf converted to swf.

My boss prefers swf.  What are the pros and cons of this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pro: Users don't need to have a PDF viewer, the UI provided by the SWF viewer may be considered superior by some, the UI may load faster, the document is hard to download (if you consider that a "pro")

Con: Users need to have a Flash Player, the UI is different from the UI the user is used to, the UI probably lacks a lot of features, the document is hard to download

There are many different mobile devices, most of which don't support Flash. Most importantly, Flash (SWF) is not and probably never will be supported on Apple iOS devices (iPhone, iPad), while PDF is supported natively. Chrome provides a built-in PDF viewer, and Firefox soon will, too.

In my personal opinion, converting PDF to SWF may have been a good idea 5 years or so ago. I would absolutely not recommend it today.